# I want to click a button inside the First View and pass a Bool to the ContentView to show the secondView inside ContentView. How i can do it?

Tags: button, swiftui, observedobject

I make Observable class with Published var

I want to click a button inside the First View and pass a Bool to the ContentView to show the secondView inside ContentView. How i can do it?

The code in my First View is:

```
class ShowPicker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pickerIsShow = false
}



struct FirstView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var showPicker = ShowPicker()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Button("showPicker"){
                self.showPicker.pickerIsShow.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The code in my ContenView is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var showPicker = ShowPicker()

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

           FirstView() 
            
            secondView().offset(y: self.showPicker.pickerIsShow ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because you declare 2 different instances of `ShowPicker`. Try:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    // Wrap your ShowPicker in an EnvironmentObject in order to access the same instance as the ContentView
    @EnvironmentObject private var showPicker: ShowPicker
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Button("showPicker"){
                self.showPicker.pickerIsShow.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // Wrap your ShowPicker in an StateObject and create it.
    @StateObject private var showPicker = ShowPicker()

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
           // pass your ShowPicker to your FirstView as an environmentObject
           FirstView()
               .environmentObject(showPicker) 
            
            secondView().offset(y: self.showPicker.pickerIsShow ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
   
        }
    }
}
```

This way both Views have access to the same instance of `ShowPicker` and can react to changes of each other.